# on exception sobre stored procedure ¿Cómo implementarlo?

Tags: sql, stored-procedure, informix

¿Cómo podría implementar el `on exception` en un procedimiento almacenado?

Tengo otro stored procedure que al insertar a la tabla `CATALOGO1` inserta en otra tabla llamada `CATPRINCIPAL`. Con ese stored procedure no tengo problema.

1. En este stored procedure lo que trato de hacer es que, cuando actualicen algún campo en `CATALOGO1` y el campo `ACTIVO` sea `True`, se actualice la tabla `CATPRINCIPAL` con los cambios.
2. Si actualizan el campo `ACTIVO` con false en `CATALOGO1`,  borro de `CATPRINCIPAL` ese registro.
3. Aquí es donde tengo el problema si deseo modificar de `CATALOGO1` el campo `ACTIVO` a TRUE, están de acuerdo que ya se borró de `CATPRINCIPAL` por lo que tendría que hacer un `INSERT` en `CATPRINCIPAL`, pero no encuentro forma de "catchar" la excepción por eso pido de su ayuda.

   Código:

   ```sql
   CREATE PROCEDURE PROC_CATALOGO1TOCATPRINCIPAL()
       REFERENCING OLD AS o NEW AS n FOR CATALOGO1; 

       IF (UPDATING and (n.activo = 't' )) THEN 
           update CATPRINCIPAL set ID_ELEMENTO = n.ID , desc_elemento = n.DESCRIPCION where id_tabla = 2 and id_elemento = o.ID;
           /*****En esta parte quiero implementar el ON EXCEPTION***/
       ELIF(UPDATING and (n.activo = 'f' )) THEN -- UPDATING Boolean operator
           delete CATPRINCIPAL where id_tabla = 2 and id_elemento = o.ID;
       END IF

   END PROCEDURE;
   ```